# Text box validation not working

Tags: c#

Right now the code below tests for a blank text box.  If it is blank it returns the error stated below the if statement.  That works fine, but I also want it to check for white spaces.  I have tried the following for the first one:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text))
```

It does not work though.  I typed the word "Bike" into the text box, but I spelled it like "B ike" with a space to see if it would return the error message and it didn't.

```
public partial class frmPersonnel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //lblError.Text = "";
        try
        {
            if (txtFirstName.Text == "")
            {
                txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter first name<br />";
            } 

            if (txtLastName.Text == "")
            {
                txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter last name! <br />";
            }
            if (txtPayRate.Text == "")
            {
                txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter pay rate! <br />";
            }
            if (txtStartDate.Text == "")
            {
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter start date! <br />";
            }
            if (txtEndDate.Text == "")
            {
                txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter end date! <br />";
            }

            DateTime dt1;
            DateTime dt2;

            dt1 = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
            dt2 = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);


            if (DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2) > 0)
            {
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Start Date must not be greater than End Date! <br />";
            }

            else
            {
                Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
                Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
                Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
                Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
                Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
                Server.Transfer("frmPersonalVerified.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` will not indicate that a string HAS white space. It will indicate that a string is composed ONLY of white space. `B ike` is not null or white space. It's a string with a space in it.

Comment: Is there a question hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the following type of test:

```
if (txtFirstName.Text == "")
```

To:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text)) // .NET 4.0+

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text)) // .NET before 4.0
```

And for your additional test (no spaces allowed in the string):

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) && !txtFirstName.Text.Contains(" ")) // .NET 4.0+

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text) && !txtFirstName.Text.Contains(" ")) // .NET before 4.0
```

Note:

You will need to check that `lblError.Text` doesn't contain anything in order to continue to the next page, as this is what holds your errors. I can only see the `DateTime` test, so even if any of your `txt` controls have failed the validation, you still transfer.

Comment: @Oded:  I used your second example and it seems that "Contain" isn't recognized in .Net 3.5

Comment: @Oded see this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094216/text-box-validation-not-working

Comment: @Mike - It's `Contains`, not `Contain`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Comment: @errorstacks - I am not in the habit of checking every question a poster has posted.

Comment: @Oded:  That's what I meant, I copied your line so I would get it exact.

Comment: @Mike - apologies. Code corrected. `Contains` is defined on `String`, not `Control`.

Comment: @Oded:  Sorry, it is running, but it still shows in the text box instead of showing the error in the label.

Comment: @Mike - That would suggest some other coding error. Assuming your code is as you posted.

Comment: @Oded Even everyone dont have that habit, i have just googled and find that question

Answer (score 1):

To do this kind of validation in Asp.Net you should really be [using the built-in validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx). If this is not desirable to you, then you might consider making your comparisons regular expression based to apply a tighter control over the inputs. In the case of your `B ike` example, you would want something like:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtFirstName.Text, @"^(\w)+$"))
{
    txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    lblError.Text += "Please enter first name<br />";
}
```

The regular expression above will make sure that there is at least one viable word character and will parse the entire string returning false if any white space is detected. It would be useful to do this for similar controls and modify the expression pattern to meet the needs of any different criteria.

**Edit:**
I left this off as assumed, but it might as well be mentioned. In order to use the Regex, you'll need to add the following using statement at the top of your code:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

**Edit 2:**
I discounted these items because you didn't ask about them, but I'll address them here since they're providing you trouble. To change the color of the TextBox in the web page you'll need to apply css to it.

Define a class in your style sheet that looks like:

```
.yellowBox
{
    background-color: #cccc00;   
}
```

Then in your block, apply the style like so:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtFirstName.Text, @"^(\w)+$"))
{
    // Define a class in your style sheet that looks like
    txtFirstName.CssClass = "yellowBox";

    // Obviously you have a lblError control, but is
    // that control visible? If not you must change its
    // visibility. This should be done after all of the
    // processing blocks are complete.
    lblError.Text += "Please enter first name<br />";
}
if ( ... next condition ... )
{

    ... 1, 2, skip a few ...
}

// If you've appended something to the lblError
// then make it visible.
if (lblError.Text.Trim().Length > 0) 
    lblError.Visible = true;
```

Comment: When I try your example I get an error under the "w" that says: Unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: @Mike: Yah, sorry about that. I posted an edit. This is a string literal and so must either be prefixed with the `@` symbol or each \ must be escaped within the string like `\\w`.

Comment: That error went away, now there is an error at "Regex" that says: The name "Regex" does not exist in the current context".

Comment: @Mike: Edit posted. You're missing a using statement that makes the Regex available without the namespace preamble.

Comment: I got the program to run, but it still shows up in the text box with the space?

Comment: @Mike: This won't change the text, it will only indicate that the text is not in a format you want.

Comment: I don't want it to change the text.  I want the error message to show up and turn the box yellow if there is a white space or a blank text box.

Comment: @Mike: That's because the manner you're using to change the colors isn't appropriate for a webpage. I didn't address those topics because they were not a part of your question. Your question dealt specifically with white space restrictions. I'll post an edit with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
if (txtFirstName.Text.Contains(" "))
{
    txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    lblError.Text += "Please enter first name without blanks<br />";             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace returns true for a null string or a string that is purely whitespace
For example "      ".

If you do not want to allow spaces in the string ie ("B ike") test the string value for spaces using Contains(' ').

Answer (score 0):

You should check the manual:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx
>
> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists **only of white-space characters**.

So use another function if you don't want any spaces (or other whitespace) to be present, like [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) or using a RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

There are various Validation possibilities, maybe have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/aspnetvalidation.aspx).

Else you can use something like

`if (txtFirstName.Text == "" && txtFirstName.Text.indexOf(" ") == -1)`

which checks for whitespaces :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((TextBox1.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
```