# Validating a text box if it is blank or has a white space

Tags: c#, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text box validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094216/text-box-validation-not-working)

Right now as the code stands it runs fine.  It returns an error in my label if no text is inputted into the text box.  When I try and add code to also check for a space within the text box such as "A pple" it doesn't work.  After the (5) text boxes are filled in the user clicks the submit button.  If all fields are correct it inputs to another page, which works fine, but if one of the text boxes isn't correct it stays on that page and shows the error.

```
public partial class frmPersonnel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtFirstName.Text == "")
            {
                txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter first name<br />";
            } 

            if (txtLastName.Text == "")
            {
                txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter last name! <br />";
            }
            if (txtPayRate.Text == "")
            {
                txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter pay rate! <br />";
            }
            if (txtStartDate.Text == "")
            {
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter start date! <br />";
            }
            if (txtEndDate.Text == "")
            {
                txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter end date! <br />";
            }

            DateTime dt1;
            DateTime dt2;

            dt1 = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
            dt2 = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);

            if (DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2) > 0)
            {
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Start Date must not be greater than End Date! <br />";
            }

            else
            {
                Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
                Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
                Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
                Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
                Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
                Server.Transfer("frmPersonalVerified.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```